# Battery Management System (BMS)

Tags: pi-3b+, battery

I'm making a UAV using raspberry pi and I understand that it does not require a complicated BMS since it won't have complicated circuitry. The only problem I'm facing right now is that of the BMS. I have also found that I can use a buck converter or a voltage testing sensor for not only voltage reduction purposes but also for battery management and battery percentage reading purposes. Can someone please advise? I want to know if I'm on the right path and my major aim is to reduce the voltage and current to specified inputs for the raspberry pi 3 B+ from a 11.1V 3S LiPo. And at the same time be able to read the battery percentage remotely. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!  I see two separate questions here.  One is easy (for me at least); the other isn't so much.

---

For powering the Pi, I have a pile of LM2596 demo boards just for that purpose.  LM2596 is the buck controller chip itself, and the demo board is the bare minimum to support it and make it work well.  Adjust the demo board with only a voltmeter attached, as they're set way high from the factory, and then connect it to the 5V pins on the Pi's GPIO header.  (ignore the USB power input)  Now you're running the Pi (almost) directly from a higher-voltage DC source.

The caveat is that powering the Pi this way bypasses the fuse that sits between the USB power connector and the 5V rail, as you're powering that rail directly.  Not a problem if your 5V supply is well-behaved, but you need to ensure that yourself, or trust that the thing you buy for that purpose is.

---

Measuring the battery is a bit more tricky, not just because the Pi itself doesn't have any kind of analog circuity whatsoever (the "ADC" is simply a digital communication interface to an external one, and the audio out is actually PWM with a very simple R-C lowpass), but also because a LiPo's discharge curve is so flat.  You can't really tell by voltage alone, until it leaves you stranded.  You really need a charge counter for that, which is another specialized chip that needs to be calibrated.
(How much charge, or how many electrons, can this particular battery hold, for example?)

---

Or you could buy a BMS module that has all of that built-in, plus a low-voltage cutoff, and cell balancing if you're also going to charge it from there.  (LiPo's don't self-balance like other chemistries do, so you'll end up after a while with one cell destroyed by overcharge at the same time that another is destroyed by deep discharge.)  Look for a 5V output that you can wire up to the Pi's GPIO header, and a communication interface of some kind that matches what you can enable on the Pi and then write (or find?) a driver for.

Have fun shopping!